# I'm having a problem that can't create react app using npx command

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npx

I can't use `npx create-react-app <projectname>` to create my react project.

The console give out this:

`Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\4536\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\is-promise\index.js //
require() of ES modules is not supported. //
require() of C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\4536\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\is-promise\index.js from C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\4536\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\run-async\index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules. //
Instead rename C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\4536\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\is-promise\index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\4536\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\is-promise\package.json.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean your `npm` cache before installing `create-react-app`.

```js
npm cache clean --force
```

Then install `create-react-app` globally.

```js
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Then you can create your react app using `create-react-app`

```js
create-react-app my-app
```

Then navigate to `my-app` and run

```
npm start
```

Comment: Cheers @TrevorWong