# npm create-react-app command not completing successfully on Windows 8

Tags: reactjs, npm

While running this command "create-react-app myapp" get stuck as shown in the below screenshot:
It's got created 3files as below in this directory "D:\usr\local\myapp"

1) **node_modules  - folder**

2) **package.json**

3) **package-lock.json**

---

D:\usr\local>create-react-app myapp

Creating a new React app in D:\usr\local\myapp.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall D:\usr\local\myapp\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_
>   modules\core-js
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall D:\usr\local\myapp\node_modules\core-js
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall D:\usr\local\myapp\node_modules\core-js-pure
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

- react-dom@16.13.1
- cra-template@1.0.3
- react-scripts@3.4.1
- react@16.13.1
  added 1606 packages from 750 contributors and audited 931424 packages in 216.515
  s

58 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

---

OR below screenshot:
[Error screenshot from cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD9OB.png)

Comment: Hello, Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61429120/im-having-a-problem-that-cant-create-react-app-using-npx-command/61429128#61429128).

Answer (score 0):

first do `npm install` then run `npm audit fix` to fix it, then run your `create-react-app myapp` to create a react app. feel free to take a look at [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/).

[Previous stack issue similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484829/npm-cant-find-package-json)

Comment: Thax Arun for the quick response. I have tried above 3 commands but it appears below error could you pls help :)

Comment: D:\>cd reactjs

D:\ReactJS>npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\ReactJS\package.j
son'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\ReactJS\package.json
'
npm WARN ReactJS No description
npm WARN ReactJS No repository field.
npm WARN ReactJS No README data
npm WARN ReactJS No license field.

up to date in 1.078s
found 0 vulnerabilities


D:\ReactJS>

Comment: again you facing same error? it is beacuse of version mismatch, please give a read on the site, i have shared.

Comment: D:\ReactJS>npm audit fix
npm ERR! code EAUDITNOPJSON
npm ERR! audit No package.json found: Cannot audit a project without a package.j
son

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-02T0
6_26_50_431Z-debug.log

D:\ReactJS>

Comment: take a look at the link i shared in my answer, "previous stack"