# How to fix ENOENT Error while installing React in WSL

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am trying to create a react app via WSL(windows subsystem for Linux), I am new to this technology, I am trying to create app in my D drive(/mnt/d). I have installed node using NVM, and it is working. But when I try to create an app using `npx create-react-app` I am getting ENOENT error, I was have been searching all over the internet from last day no luck so far, can anyone have a solution or show me what I am doing wrong. Attaching the error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61429120/im-having-a-problem-that-cant-create-react-app-using-npx-command/61429128#61429128)

Answer (score 0):

npx can be a bit weird around getting correct working directory context right. Try installing create-react-app globally ( `npm i -g create-react-app` ). Then try running it without npx.